# How do I automatically space the multiple pictures to fit equally across the width of the screen ' html

Tags: html, css

How do I automatically space the pictures to the size of the screen ' html

Comment: You need to provide a minimum example for us to diagnose your issue

Comment: Please provide an example of what you want. Are wanting a single picture the full width or multiple pictures spaced in columns?

Comment: I have 3 pictures in a row I want to have equal space either side of the middle pic so that the first img starts at left then space middle img then space then right img but the " space " equal both sides of the middle img

Comment: So it fills width of screen

Comment: can we see your code?

Answer (score 0):

Yeah please post your html and css.

Otherwise what is really useful if your making a gallery is to crop your pictures to equal height and width, and then add

```
img{
width:100%;
}
```

I would avoid setting the height unless you make all your pictures equal height as it may make responsive a little funky. Height should automatically be set by the size of the containing element if the width is set to 100%;

Comment: Not that how do I put images on ?

Comment: I have 3 pictures in a row I want to have equal space either side of the middle pic so that the first img starts at left then space middle img then space then right img but the " space " equal both sides of the middle img

Comment: you need to post your CSS and HTML because we don't know what you are doing so far..

Comment: Make a class container and set it width to 100%;

then nest your images inside a div with a width of 30%, set the display to inline-block and margin to 0 auto. 

alternatively you can float the images left and apply clearfix to the container.

Answer (score 0):

Ths is an example to get images evenly & horizontally in a Div via CSS;

**CSS**

```
#thumbs {   
    width: 540px;
    margin-top:90px;
    margin-left: auto; 
    margin-right: auto;

     text-align: justify;
    -ms-text-justify: distribute-all-lines;
    text-justify: distribute-all-lines;
}
#thumbs a {
    vertical-align: top;
    display: inline-block;
    *display: inline;
    zoom: 1;
}
.stretch {
    width: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 0;
    line-height: 0
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="thumbs">
    <a id="single_image1" href="#"><img src="http://dummyimage.com/150x150/444/fff" alt=""/></a>
    <a id="single_image2" href="#"><img src="http://dummyimage.com/150x150/444/fff" alt=""/></a>
    <a id="single_image3" href="#"><img src="http://dummyimage.com/150x150/444/fff" alt=""/></a>
    <span class="stretch"></span>
</div>​
```

Comment: http://kjs-coding-solutions.netau.net have a look you will know what I mean